# why it shows error for wpdb insert sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, mysqli

### I'm trying simple code with 2 tables(1 customer may have 1 or more phone number):

```
$wpdb->insert('Customer',array('mtrname' => $_POST['amtrname'],
                               'test' => $_POST['atest'],
                               'password' => $_POST['apassword'] ));
```

**Then trying to get the id_customer as FK for table Phones:**

```
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

**Then insert:**

```
 $wpdb->insert('Phones',array('number' => $_POST['anumber'],
                         'id_customer' => $lastid ));
```

**In DB it works but I get this error :**

> WordPress database error: [] INSERT INTO `Phones` (`number`,
>   `id_customer`) VALUES ('8', '63')

---

Why I have such an error? All I want to do is linking 2 tables with 1 foreign key as I have "1 to Many" relationship

```
Customer
- id_customer   // primary key, autoincrement
- mtrname  // a varchar
- test  // a varchar
- password // a varchar

Phones
- id_phone    // primary key, autoincrement
- number  // a varchar
- id_customer // foreign key reference to Customer
```

Comment: I'm definitely (thankfully) not a PHP expert, but it seems like you need to iterate the array and generate an insert statement for each item in the array. OR a temp table perhaps.

Comment: I just have 2 columns in table Phone (number and id_customer : reference to the id_customer in the first table), didn't know how to make the join :/ I used SET it worked well but outside wordpress... with wordpress it didn't work :/

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is you probably need to run the insert for each record in the array.

Comment: Please check in config that wodb not showing errors. Have you tried `$wpdb->print_error();` ?

Comment: Can you share the **exact** table structure?

Comment: sure.. I edited and I put the tables

Comment: So, according to that pseudo table structure, your tables are prefixed with `TAB_`, while your code is not. Could that be the problem?

Comment: no actually names of both of tables : Customer , Phones
I just added TAB to say that it's a table .. sorry for that I will change again

Comment: and I got data , the insert is working well but that error shows too so I don't know why I got that error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the solution if someone needs it :

well, I found out that the error comes because I wrote both of these together:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();
```

When I use just one of them, I don't get any error(I still don't know the logic behind but fine..).

Thanks for your comments and thank you 'Suhas Bachhav' for that hint.